# How to add sass-loader with Webpack 1?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, webpack-2, create-react-app, sass-loader

I recently ejected my create-react-app because I need to load sass files. Unfortunately, create-react-app uses webpack 1. But, the current version of sass-loader includes a dependency on webpack 2. The support docs don't indicate the last sass-loader version that supports webpack 1. Does anyone know where I can find this info?

Comment: sass-loader at github

Comment: and the on the release tab see the differences

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to use the webpack 1 branch of the loader:
https://github.com/webpack-contrib/sass-loader/tree/archive/webpack-1

As shown in the documentation:

`module.exports = {
  ...
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        loaders: ["style-loader", "css-loader", "sass-loader"]
      }
    ]
  }
};`

And then in your react app:

```
require("./file.scss")
```

In your npm install you'd do:
    npm i -S npm install sass-loader@4.1.1